# Transfecting cocoon or chrysalis

Tags: molecular-biology, entomology, development

Do you know whether anybody tried to transfect insects during their cocoon/chrysalis stage, and if so do you have a link to such studies?

I was thinking it would be easier to do given that it's a more macroscopic manipulation than during initial development, and that — given that the organism dissolves itself — one could obtain (almost?) organism-wide coverage via a simple injection.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How much material are you thinking? I'll confess right off the bat that I know very little about transfection, but what method would you use (viral? Chemical, e.g. cationic lipids/ other?)? What do you want to introduce into the cell(s)? A small amount might infect (sorry, transfer genetic material) into a few cells, but how do you know how much might harm/kill the organism, or does that not matter? Sorry for all the questions, but it might be better if you clarify re. intent. You may very well know far more about this than I do.

Comment: > What do you want to introduce into the cell(s)?
Either DNA or RNA. As for the rest of the questions regarding methodology, I think that's what an answer would contain.